# Why one should almost always show alert dialog through onCreateDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

A few days ago, I asked a question concerning alert dialog [AlertDialog is this a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669948/alertdialog-is-this-a-bug) Before asking the question I went through a number of posts about alert dialog. On all the questions I read, all use show() to show the dialog. I do not know whether the questioners actually use the posted codes on their apps or not. If they are then, unless the activity is portrait or landscape only, they should show the dialog by using showDialog(int id). The reason for this is the OS will take care of orientation change for you only when using showDialog. This is illustrated in the code below. Just click on the button and then rotate your device to see what will happen.

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/with_show_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clickable = "true"
        android:text="With Show"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/no_show_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/with_show_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clickable = "true"
        android:text="No Show"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/no_on_create_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/no_show_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clickable = "true"
        android:text="Not Using onCreateDialog"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code**

```
public class AlertAndShowActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    static final int DIALOG_SHOW_ID = 1;
    static final int DIALOG_NO_SHOW_ID = 2;
    static final int DIALOG_NOT_USING_ONCREATEDIALOG_ID = 3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button showBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.with_show_btn);
        showBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button noShowBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.no_show_btn);
        noShowBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button notUsingOnCreateDialogBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.no_on_create_btn);
        notUsingOnCreateDialogBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    protected AlertDialog createDialog(final int id)
    {       
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Dismiss is not enough");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                // When dialog is showing through showDialog(int id)
                // and show() is called, then calling cancel will dismiss 
                // the dialog but it will reappear on orientation change.
                // When you run this, chick WithShow and then click Cancel 
                // and rotate your device to see what I mean.
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                // system will automatically call dismiss
                // see also remark for the cancel case above.
            }
        });

        builder.setNeutralButton("Good", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
                        @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                // This will produce the behavior that one wants when show() 
                // is used in the code. That is the dialog will not reappear
                // on orientation change.
                removeDialog(id);   
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }

    protected AlertDialog createDialogWithShow(int id)
    {   
        AlertDialog alertDlg = createDialog(id);
        // Only call show if you want to disable a button.
        // You can only disable a button after calling show(),
        // otherwise you will get null pointer exception.
        alertDlg.show();
        //alertDlg.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);

        return alertDlg;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            // notUsingOnCreateDialogBtn 
            case R.id.no_on_create_btn:
                // this will create the dialog and show it on the UI
                // but if one rotates the device it will not be
                // automatically recreated.
                createDialogWithShow(DIALOG_NOT_USING_ONCREATEDIALOG_ID);
                break;

            // withShowBtn
            case R.id.with_show_btn:
                // OS will recreate the dialog on orientation change.
                showDialog(DIALOG_SHOW_ID);
                break;

            case R.id.no_show_btn:
                showDialog(DIALOG_NO_SHOW_ID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
        // no case here for DIALOG_NOT_USING_ONCREATEDIALOG_ID
        // since it is not shown using showDialog
        switch (id)
        {
            case DIALOG_NO_SHOW_ID:
                return createDialog(id);

            case DIALOG_SHOW_ID:
                return createDialogWithShow(DIALOG_SHOW_ID);

            default:
                return super.onCreateDialog(id);
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: While this is terrific example, you should post it as an andwer to one of the questions related to the alert dialog.

Comment: *Why one should almost always show alert dialog through onCreateDialog*, better not. The behavior is known + that method is deprecated now.