# Not to dismiss dialog when possitiveButton pressed

Tags: android, dialog, radio-button

My Android app has a dialog with possitive button and 3 radio button.
2 of 3 are wrong answer and 1 is correct answer.
When user select wrong answer and press possitiveButton as OK,
I don't want to dismiss the dialog and display toast message to say 
your choice is incorrect.
Then user can re-select another answer and press OK,
if the answer is correct, I want to dismiss the dialog.
I'd like to know how not to dismiss the dialog when possitiveButton is pressed.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669948/alertdialog-is-this-a-bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the Click method for the positiveButton.

```
AlertDialog.Builder db = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
db.setPositiveButton("OK", new 
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

       if (rb1.isChecked() || rb2.isChecked() ){  //here make the toast}
            }
        });
       else { //dismiss here}
AlertDialog dialog = db.show();
```

where rb1 and rb2 are the wrong radiobuttons

Comment: Thank you for your code. But my problem is when I press PositiveButton, the dialog dismissed even if I don't write dismiss().

Comment: so if you now check rb1 (the wrong answer) and click ok, the dialog gets dismissed?  In this case try the updated code.

Comment: I found the onClickListener of setPositiveButton must dismiss the dialog. Therefore I disable it and setOnClickListener as getButton( DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE ). This works fine. Thank yo all!

Answer (score 1):

I'll give u an example

```
AlertDialog.builder builder = new Builder(this);
builder.setPositiveButxxxxx(xxxxxx)
{
     onClick(AlertDialog alert)
     {
          //if you want to dissmiss here,
          alert.dismiss();
          //else
          //do nothing
     }
}
```